# Was bestimmt die Reihenfolge von Modalverben in einem Aussagesatz?

Tags: modal-verb

Wieso sagt man `Er muss das können, wenn er ausgelernt hat.` aber nicht `Er kann das sollen, wenn er ausgelernt hat.`?
Oder `Das sollst du können.` und nicht `Das kannst du sollen.`?
Danke Sie für Antworten.

Comment: *Mögen hätte ich schon wollen, aber dürfen hab ich mich nicht getraut* - Karl Valentin

Comment: Da die Reihenfolge der Verschachtelung die Bedeutung der Aussage ändert, kann nur die Satzbedeutung die Reihenfolge bestimmen. Es ist also nicht wie z.B. bei gereihten Adjektiven, wo es weitere , willkürlich erscheinende Gesetzmäßigkeiten gibt.

Comment: @KilianFoth Alles klar, danke. Das mit den Adjektiven ist ein guter Vergleich, da gibt es ja eine bestimmte Abfolge. Hier ist es also ausschließlich die Bedeutung.

Comment: @tofro: sei vorsichtig, wenn du das zitierst: https://www.damm-legal.de/lg-muenchen-zur-urheberrechtswidrigen-zitierung-von-karl-valentins-spruch-moegen-haette-ich-schon-wollen-aber-duerfen-hab-ich-mich-nicht-getraut

Comment: @bakunin Was ein Irrsinn.

Comment: @EagleFliesBanana: Zum Inhalt desines Kommentars will ich mich nicht äußern. Aber da wir hier im Sprachforum sind, besser klingt für mich als Muttersprachler: *Was für ein Irrsinn.*

Comment: @UweGeuder Danke. Das ist wohl Umgangssprache.

Answer (score 2):

"können" ist in diesem Fall kein Modalverb bzw. wird nicht als solches benutzt. Es bedeutet

> die geistige, körperliche Fähigkeit zu etw. haben
>
> etw. verstehen, beherrschen
>
> etw. Gelerntes wiederzugeben vermögen

(Quelle: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/k%C3%B6nnen))

Da im Deutschen das konjugierte Verb immer an Position 2 steht, handelt es sich hier nicht um unterschiedliche Wortreihenfolgen mit derselben Bedeutung, sondern es ergeben sich unterschiedliche Bedeutungen:

> Das sollst du können -> Wir können von Dir erwarten, dass du das verstehst/beherrschst
>
> <strike>Das kannst du sollen</strike> -> Du bist in der Lage, das zu sollen

Das zweite Beispiel ist allerdings ‒ mit wenigen, sehr konstruierten Ausnahmen ‒ nicht sinnvoll.

*Edit: Ergänzung nach Kommentar von tofro*

Comment: Man kann sich durchaus Fälle konstruieren, die "Das kannst du sollen" zu einer möglichen Formulierung machen. +1 für "das primäre Verb steht an Position 2".

Answer (score 1):

Die Modalverben "müssen" und "sollen" werden normalerweise verwendet, um eine Verpflichtung auszudrücken, während "können" verwendet wird, um eine Fähigkeit auszudrücken.
Daher ist es korrekt, "Er muss das können, wenn er ausgelernt hat" zu sagen, um auszudrücken, dass er in der Lage sein muss, bestimmte Aufgaben zu erledigen, um seine Ausbildung erfolgreich abzuschließen.

Umgekehrt ist es nicht üblich, "Er kann das sollen" zu sagen, da "sollen" normalerweise eine Verpflichtung ausdrückt, während "können" die Fähigkeit ausdrückt, etwas zu tun.

Daher ist es korrekt, "Das sollst du können" zu sagen, um auszudrücken, dass du in der Lage sein musst, etwas zu tun, um eine bestimmte Anforderung zu erfüllen.

Insgesamt hängt die Verwendung von Modalverben in der deutschen Sprache von dem Kontext ab, in dem sie verwendet werden.

Comment: Also ist die Frage über Logik von Bedeutung, nicht Grammatik? Ok

Comment: Mit dem Kontext hat das eigentlich überhaupt nichts zu tun. Sondern damit, wo das primäre Verb in einem deutschen Satz steht.